# Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void' in ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am fetching data from google Api in the function of `details.ts` file, i have created service for that, as bellow. its displaing Typescript error `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'`

```
this.typeApi.getTypeDetails(baseUrl).then(data => {
});
```

in `type-api.service.ts` file, I have fetch data from google Api as bellow,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http /*, Response*/ } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';



@Injectable()
export class TypeApi {

constructor(public http: Http ) {}

getTypeDetails(PlaceUrl){
        this.http
        .get(PlaceUrl)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            (data) => data,
            (err) =>  err); // Reach here if fails
}

}
```

in package.json file,

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.4.8",
"@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
"@angular/core": "2.4.8",
"@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
"@angular/http": "2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
"@ionic-native/core": "3.1.0",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.4.4",
"@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^3.4.4",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.1.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.1.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"ionic-angular": "2.3.0",
"ionic2-rating": "^1.2.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
"zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
"devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
"typescript": "2.0.9"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree whith Gunter,
Additionally I'd suggest you to set method (function) return type everywhere possible, in order to see the type of result the caller will receive.
For the care above:

Assuming that your **TypeApi** will be reused in multiple callers

```
public getTypeDetails(apiUrl: string) : Observable<any>{
       return this.http.get(apiUrl)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .catch((error) => this.handleError(error));; 
}
```

//An example of `handleError` function

```
private handleError (error: any) {
    // Could dig deeper into the error to get a better message or use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

Then, when you call this method, you have to subscribe to the result the method will return:

```
this.typeApi.getTypeDetails(theUrl).subscribe(result => {
    //here you have the analog success function from an ajax call 
    //use the received data
   }, 
   error => {
       //here you have the analog error function from an ajax call 
       //treat the error
   }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

For this to work you'd need to return a `Promise` from `getTypeDetails` like

```
getTypeDetails(PlaceUrl){
    return    this.http
        .get(PlaceUrl)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .toPromise();
}
```

but just returning the `Observable` is usually the better way

```
getTypeDetails(PlaceUrl){
    return    this.http
        .get(PlaceUrl)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

with

```
this.typeApi.getTypeDetails(baseUrl).subscribe(data => {
});
```

Comment: its displaying `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<{}>'.` Typescript error.

Comment: If you use `toPromise()` then you need to use `then` like in the code in your question. If you don't use `toPromise()` then you can use `subscribe()` like in the 2nd example in my answer. It seems you somehow mixed these two approaches.

Comment: i didn't use `toPromise()` but still its displaying `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<{}>' Typescript error.

Comment: That's quite unlikely. Hard for me to know what's going on. It's not from the code you posted.